# error when training a caffe model

Tags: python, caffe

I am trying to train a model with my own data though it starts training after  a few iterations it throws an error.This is what it looks like

```
0803 13:41:12.052456  3772 solver.cpp:237]     Train net output #2: 
loss = 1.82591 (* 1 = 1.82591 loss)
I0803 13:41:12.052477  3772 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 120, lr = 
9.92e -05
F0803 13:41:18.020836  3779 data_transformer.cpp:168] Check failed: 
height <= datum_height (227 vs. 224) 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f8f7b14adaa  (unknown)
    @     0x7f8f7b14ace4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f8f7b14a6e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f8f7b14d687  (unknown)
    @     0x7f8f7b7ba9e0  caffe::DataTransformer<>::Transform()
    @     0x7f8f7b835a2f  caffe::DataLayer<>::load_batch()
    @     0x7f8f7b8c6a5c  
caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::InternalThreadEntry()
    @     0x7f8f7b79aa30  caffe::InternalThread::entry()
    @     0x7f8f7b79b376  boost::detail::thread_data<>::run()
    @     0x7f8f7172aa4a  (unknown)
    @     0x7f8f6bd73184  start_thread
    @     0x7f8f79a7dffd  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I do think that the problem may be with input images,any suggestions as to  what i should change or edit?

Comment: your input image network definition height is larger(227) than your input image(224) .change the deifinition(train.prototxt) dim 2: from 227 to  224

Comment: Thanks for your time.ill try that

Comment: let me know how it goes

Comment: Sorry for the late reply-Now i get `I0806 09:41:02.010442  2992 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 360, lr = 9.76e-05
F0806 09:41:20.544955  2998 data_transformer.cpp:168] Check failed: height <= datum_height (224 vs. 199)` Any ideas on what i should do?

Comment: i think you need to see in data_transformer.cpp to see where it is failing

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple images in a batch but they have varying sizes? You need to standardize the image sizes. You could [use OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to do this before feeding your images into Caffe.